# Get removed ID back

Tags: jquery

Once I remove the ID, I can't get that ID back,
I have to call the same ID in other condition, suppose my code is like this:

```
if (completed == 'A') {
    jQuery("#language_edit").remove();
    jQuery("#addeducation").remove();
}
if (completed == 'B') {
    jQuery("#language_edit").show();
    jQuery("#addeducation").show();
}
```

Comment: I will have to use Remove(), so that No one can do Display: block from firebug,

its a secure Site

Comment: There is More jQuery on click, #language_edit, if I use hide(), and show(), 

anyone can easily do it display: none, and that extra jQuery can be enable

Comment: Er.. in what way is that relevant? If your ideas about security are along the lines of "modifying the dom will prevent (malicious) users from doing x because they can't then click the link" - you're very much mistaken =). If you aren't performing server-side authorization checks when somebody does something, your app is basically wide open to attack.

Answer (score 4):

`.remove()` will delete the dom element

```
if (completed == 'A')
{
   jQuery("#language_edit").hide();
   jQuery("#addeducation").hide();
}
if (completed == 'B')
{ 
   jQuery("#language_edit").show();
   jQuery("#addeducation").show();
}
```

Comment: There is More jQuery on click, #language_edit,.. if I use hide(), and show(), 

anyone can easily do it display: none, and that extra jQuery can be enable

Comment: @AlokJha and what would you do if user has copied the html before and add it manually through the console after we removing it through scripts..?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.hide();` not `remove();` in your code

```
if (completed == 'A')
{
jQuery("#language_edit").hide();
jQuery("#addeducation").hide();
}
if (completed == 'B')
{ 
   jQuery("#language_edit").show();
   jQuery("#addeducation").show();
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpcBL/)**

Comment: I will have to use Remove(), so that No one can do Display: block from firebug,

its a secure Site

Comment: @AlokJha If you shouldn't be able to make it visible again with Firebug, how do you expect jQuery to do it? If it was possible with jQuery, then one could simply make that jQuery call from Firebug.

Comment: Hmm, i think you should not use jquery if its about something secure cause its a front-end framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to hide those elements

```
jQuery("#language_edit").hide(); // use hide() instead of remove()
```

`.remove()` will remove your element from DOM, and once removed you can't get them back

Comment: No I wil lhave to use remove(),
There is More jQuery on click, #language_edit, if I use hide(), and show(), 

anyone can easily do it display: none, and that extra jQuery can be enable

Answer (score 0):

Once you remove it, it is gone from the web page. If you are just trying to hide it, you could just use `hide()` instead of `remove()`.

```
if (completed == 'A')
{
    jQuery("#language_edit").hide();
    jQuery("#addeducation").hide();
}
if (completed == 'B')
{ 
    jQuery("#language_edit").show();
    jQuery("#addeducation").show();
}
```